# How to create a new Linux kernel scheduler

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, scheduler

Looking through the scheduler source code (2.6.34, kernel/sched.c), I can see how the "pluggable" schedulers are used, and I believe I understand the interface to be implemented.  What I don't understand yet is how to get my code built into the kernel.  At the very least, pointers to other sites would be appreciated.

Right now, I'm grepping for SCHED_FIFO, SCHED_RR, and SCHED_NORMAL in the kernel source tree, so really I'm looking for a more insightful way to look at it :-)

EDIT: As some background, I'm very familiar with the FreeBSD scheduler (and the FreeBSD kernel in general), so I'm not looking for pointers on how to do process/thread level scheduling.  I'm looking for a way to add my own scheduler alongside the normal linux schedulers (similar to SCHED_FIFO).

EDIT #2:  The BFS pointer below is a good start, but it still rips CFS out of the kernel.  sched.c now looks like:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_SCHED_BFS
#include "sched_bfs.c"
#else
   // original sched.c 
#endif // CONFIG_SCHED_BFS
```

I'd love to see an answer or a pointer on how to do this a little better (ie, keep CFS, at least for right now).

EDIT #3:  I've answered my own question below, as I think I've figured it out.

Comment: Do you mean adding the appropriate bits in kconfig so your scheduler can be selected / used?

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I'm looking for -- I've added a little bit of background to the original question (the FreeBSD stuff), to hopefully make what I'm looking for more clear.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've figured out the answer to my question, so I thought I'd add it here.  Below is the patch that will add a new scheduler to the 2.6.34 vanilla kernel.  Right now, I've only compiled the kernel.  I fully expect running a system with this EXACT patch will cause it to crash -- so use at your own risk :-)

```
diff --git a/include/linux/sched.h b/include/linux/sched.h
index 2b7b81d..a2a2b21 100644
--- a/include/linux/sched.h
+++ b/include/linux/sched.h
@@ -37,6 +37,7 @@
 #define SCHED_RR       2
 #define SCHED_BATCH        3
 /* SCHED_ISO: reserved but not implemented yet */
+#define SCHED_NEW               4 /* Stealing from SCHED_ISO */
 #define SCHED_IDLE     5
 /* Can be ORed in to make sure the process is reverted back to SCHED_NORMAL on fork */
 #define SCHED_RESET_ON_FORK     0x40000000
diff --git a/init/Kconfig b/init/Kconfig
index eb77e8c..0055d26 100644
--- a/init/Kconfig
+++ b/init/Kconfig
@@ -23,6 +23,11 @@ config CONSTRUCTORS

 menu "General setup"

+config SCHED_NEW
+       bool "NEW cpu scheduler"
+       ---help---
+         Brand new scheduler 
+
 config EXPERIMENTAL
    bool "Prompt for development and/or incomplete code/drivers"
    ---help---
diff --git a/kernel/sched.c b/kernel/sched.c
index 3c2a54f..588960d 100644
--- a/kernel/sched.c
+++ b/kernel/sched.c
@@ -1931,6 +1931,7 @@ static void deactivate_task(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, int sleep)

 #include "sched_idletask.c"
 #include "sched_fair.c"
+#include "sched_new.c"
 #include "sched_rt.c"
 #ifdef CONFIG_SCHED_DEBUG
 # include "sched_debug.c"
diff --git a/kernel/sched_new.c b/kernel/sched_new.c
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..c2e269e
--- /dev/null
+++ b/kernel/sched_new.c
@@ -0,0 +1,140 @@
+#ifdef CONFIG_SCHED_NEW
+
+/*
+ * Starting with a simple, 1 runq per cpu scheduler.  Don't care
+ * about fairness for right now.  Just get it up and running to 
+ * verify that we have the interface correct
+ */
+
+static void
+enqueue_task_new(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, int wakeup, bool head)
+{
+}
+
+static void dequeue_task_new(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, int sleep)
+{
+}
+
+static void yield_task_new(struct rq *rq)
+{
+}
+
+static void check_preempt_curr_new(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, int flags)
+{
+}
+
+static struct task_struct *pick_next_task_new(struct rq *rq)
+{
+}
+
+static void put_prev_task_new(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p)
+{
+}
+
+#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
+static int select_task_rq_new(struct task_struct *p, int sd_flag, int flags)
+{
+}
+static void pre_schedule_new(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *prev)
+{
+}
+
+static void post_schedule_new(struct rq *rq)
+{
+}
+
+static void task_woken_new(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p)
+{
+}
+
+static void task_waking_new(struct rq *this_rq, struct task_struct *task)
+{
+}
+static void set_cpus_allowed_new(struct task_struct *p,
+               const struct cpumask *new_mask)
+{
+}
+/* Assumes rq->lock is held */
+static void rq_online_new(struct rq *rq)
+{
+}
+
+/* Assumes rq->lock is held */
+static void rq_offline_new(struct rq *rq)
+{
+}
+#endif /* COMFIG_SMP */
+
+static void set_curr_task_new(struct rq *rq)
+{
+}
+
+
+static void task_tick_new(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, int queued)
+{
+} 
+
+static void task_fork_new(struct task_struct *p)
+{
+}
+static void switched_from_new(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p,
+              int running)
+{
+}
+static void switched_to_new(struct rq *this_rq, struct task_struct *task,
+               int running)
+{
+}
+static void prio_changed_new(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p,
+               int oldprio, int running)
+{
+}
+static unsigned int get_rr_interval_new(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *task)
+{
+}
+
+
+
+static const struct sched_class new_sched_class = {
+   .next           = &fair_sched_class,
+   .enqueue_task       = enqueue_task_new,
+   .dequeue_task       = dequeue_task_new,
+   .yield_task     = yield_task_new,
+
+   .check_preempt_curr = check_preempt_curr_new,
+
+   .pick_next_task     = pick_next_task_new,
+   .put_prev_task      = put_prev_task_new,
+
+#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
+   .select_task_rq     = select_task_rq_new,
+
+   .pre_schedule       = pre_schedule_new,
+   .post_schedule      = post_schedule_new,
+
+   .task_waking            = task_waking_new,
+   .task_woken     = task_woken_new,
+
+   .set_cpus_allowed       = set_cpus_allowed_new,
+
+   .rq_online              = rq_online_new,
+   .rq_offline             = rq_offline_new,
+#endif
+
+   .set_curr_task          = set_curr_task_new,
+   .task_tick      = task_tick_new,
+   .task_fork              = task_fork_new,
+
+   .switched_from          = switched_from_new,
+   .switched_to        = switched_to_new,
+
+   .prio_changed       = prio_changed_new,
+
+   .get_rr_interval    = get_rr_interval_new,
+#ifdef CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED
+   .moved_group            = NULL
+#endif
+};
+
+#endif /* CONFIG_SCHED_NEW */
diff --git a/kernel/sched_rt.c b/kernel/sched_rt.c
index b5b920a..aaf4beb 100644
--- a/kernel/sched_rt.c
+++ b/kernel/sched_rt.c
@@ -1731,7 +1731,11 @@ static unsigned int get_rr_interval_rt(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *task)
 }

 static const struct sched_class rt_sched_class = {
+#ifdef CONFIG_SCHED_NEW
+   .next           = &new_sched_class,
+#else
    .next           = &fair_sched_class,
+#endif /* CONFIG_SCHED_NEW */
    .enqueue_task       = enqueue_task_rt,
    .dequeue_task       = dequeue_task_rt,
    .yield_task     = yield_task_rt,
```

Answer (score 17):

Embedded.com has a 3-part entry that walks through implementing a simple real-time scheduler:

- [part 1](http://www.embedded.com/design/operating-systems/4204929/Real-Time-Linux-Scheduling-Part-1)
- [part 2](http://www.embedded.com/design/operating-systems/4204971/Real-Time-Linux-Scheduling-Part-2)
- [part 3](http://www.embedded.com/design/operating-systems/4204980/Real-Time-Linux-Scheduling-Part-3)

Unlike the other answers, this one is created as a tutorial:

> [...] in the literature we did not find documents that explain how
>   to implement a new scheduling policy for Linux.
>
> [...]
>
> In this document, we have presented in a [sic] depth description all steps
>   required to implement a new scheduling policy.
>
> [...]
>
> This is a simple implementation of that scheduling algorithm. However,
>   advanced issues, like interruptions, timers and multiprocessor systems, just to mention some, are out of the scope of this article.

Comment: The links are broken. I couldn't find them anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: @zeronone they seem ok for me today. Maybe they were just broken temporarily?

Comment: Yup the links work might've been a temporary issue

Answer (score 10):

[Con Kolivas Brainfuck Scheduler](http://ck.kolivas.org/patches/bfs/).
 I just found this by googling.  It may be an example to start from.

Comment: I've looked through BFS's design, and it's definitely interesting.  It's simplicity is awesome.  However, I want to add a scheduler that co-exists with CFS (and SCHED_FIFO, etc.), and I'm looking for how to get the configuration right, not how to rip out the existing scheduler and reimplement my own.

Comment: So, I spent a little more time looking at the BFS patch, and I was wrong.  It did show at least one way to add a new scheduler giving me a shortcut to adding my code.

Thanks for the pointer blm!