# schedule() function linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have an assignment to modify the scheduler code for linux kernel and I am stuck at the first point in my assignment. I am unable to find which file the schedule() is implemented. I am a newbie and for sure I feel that there would be some structured way to find which specific files functions are in. Any help appriciated.

[EDIT] I have source of kernel version 3.5.4

Comment: Might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3086864/274261

Comment: Do u want to implement a new scheduling algo? or just switch to an already available kernel scheduler?

Comment: Actually the assignment is to implement lottery scheduling algorithm but I am stuck at this first place, unable to find `schedule()` function location.

Comment: It should be in `kernel/sched.c` file.

Comment: @askmish That is what I was trying to find but I think that in version 3.5.4 there is no such file. There is one with the name `sched.h` but that would not do. Can you please see or give some pointers how to find it

Comment: Then it should be at: kernel/sched/core.c Alternatively you could grep for schedule() in the linux directory. :)

Comment: despite of the answer to your specific question, a useful tool that you can use to inspect quickly the linux kernel code is: http://lxr.linux.no/+trees  I found it really useful when I need to study the LKCF stack (Linux Kernel Cripto Framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

schedule() function is implemented in: [linux/kernel/sched/core.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.6/kernel/sched/core.c#L3462)

if you want to learn more about [process scheduling](http://www.makelinux.net/books/ulk3/understandlk-CHP-7), ULK3 is probably perfect for you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am new for linux kernel too. For navigation through linux kernel code I use:

- **cscope** which is a good tool. There is a [guide](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/large_projects.html) for using cscope with large projects such as linux kernel.
- **[Online Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident)**. Especially the identifier search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find some function name, you can use
`grep -r "schedule"`
in the root of source tree and if you have ctags you can navigate to his definition from any occurrence of his call.