# Implementing lottery scheduling algorithm in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I have to implement a lottery scheduling algorithm for kernel. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086864/how-to-create-a-new-linux-kernel-scheduler) on SO is quite helpful but on older version of kernel. Moreover I would like to where are other scheduling algorithms are implemented. I mean where I can find the source code related to, say round robin scheduling, in the kernel source.

Any help appriciated