# how to implement new scheduling scheme in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am new to Linux kernel development
can anyone tell me how to implement a new scheduling scheme in linux kernel?

Which files do I need to change etc . A step by step guide would be helpfull

Comment: What research have you done? What resources have you found already?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a new Linux kernel scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086864/how-to-create-a-new-linux-kernel-scheduler)

Answer (score 2):

A step by step guide? no problem boss.

1. read [Process Scheduling](http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html).
2. [How to create a new Linux kernel scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086864/how-to-create-a-new-linux-kernel-scheduler)

you can set your `zero` task to get familiar with these function list:

[image]