# Linux Kernel Scheduling Implementation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I and my friends are trying to find out a way to implement new (actually old :) ) kernel scheduling algorithm for SCHED_NORMAL and SCHED_BATCH classes. In other words, we are trying to implement Round Robin or FIFO behaviors instead of Fair Scheduling algorithm. We have been reading kernel code, we had some progress but it is not enough. What is the known way to start this process? How can we start (Start implementing these algorithms)?

Thank you

Comment: The Linux kernel already supports real-time scheduling; both Round Robin and FIFO policies are supported.  See `sched_setscheduler()` manual page for details.

Comment: @esorton Do you suggest we just need to set the policy to SCHED_RR and everything will work than?

Comment: Yes.  You don't need to implement a new scheduling algorithm unless you want to do it for a learning experience.  If you set a process's schedule policy to SCHED_RR it will run at a real-time priority.  Processes with a policy of SCHED_RR or SCHED_FIFO will run before processes with a policy of SCHED_NORMAL.

Comment: @esorton That sounds great. But, is there any other way to replace that algorithms with SCHED_NORMAL CFS. Do we need to replace all the structure for this in the sched.c?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the kernel side of things, just the user level.  If you do want to implement your own scheduler, I noticed this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086864/how-to-create-a-new-linux-kernel-scheduler, a bit old but may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> We have been reading kernel code, we had some progress but it is not
>   enough. What is the known way to start this process? How can we start
>   (Start implementing these algorithms)?

Well, these concepts are bit complex and greatly evolved so you should begin to understand the algorithm and concept about these from the below reference.Once you understand reading kernel code should be started. This should be the approach.

you may want to refer the great classic books which describes these concepts and the implementation in detailed way.

1. "**[The Design Of UNIX Operating System"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997) By Maurice J Bach** (Chapter08)
2. **[Linux Kernel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468) By Robert Love** (Chapter04)

Comment: We are using Love's book and we already read Chapter 4. Also we have idea about the scheduling algorithms. Our problem is starting the process. I was thinking getting sched_fair.c code and modify it or getting sched_rt.c and modify it. However, I don't know how to communicate with sched.c. In other words, what kind of structure we need for sched.c.