# Replace Linux Scheduler

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scheduler

I have a task to write and replace Linux Scheduler.

I've read about two types of schedulers: I\O and  task scheduler. As I understand, I need to look into process.

But I can't find any information, all I see is how to add scheduler to a list in

```
/sys/block/hda/queue/scheduler
```

But it seems it's not just adding one line to a file, replacing scheduler requires changing some files in kernel.

Where could I find information about what files are linking with scheduler and how to implement my own scheduler in Linux?

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3086864/

Answer (score 1):

You can find this documentation so helpful under: /usr/src/linux/Documentation/block/switching-sched.txt

Also you can see the patch found in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086864/how-to-create-a-new-linux-kernel-scheduler?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to create a new Linux kernel scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086864/how-to-create-a-new-linux-kernel-scheduler?noredirect=1&lq=1)